# Error In Ajax call During bind json data to Dropdown

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I'm Try to bind json data to  HTML dropdown using ajax call.

My AJAX call

```
function ajaxCall(paramurl, paramControlId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        crossDomin: true,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            var dropdata;
            $.each(data, function (i) {
                dropdata = dropdata + "<option value='" + data[i].ListKey + "'>" + data[i].ListValue + "</option>";
            });
            $(paramControlId).html($(paramControlId).html() + dropdata);
        },
        error: errorResponse

    });
    function errorResponse(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

        alert('Error on Ajax Call' + '\n Status: ' + xhr.status + '\n Response Text: ' + xhr.responseText + '\n Error: ' + thrownError);
    }
}
```

Problem:

1.It's work fine in all browser but most of times it's not work in IE.

2.If i use **debugger**; before the **$.ajax({**  code it's not run success function it's directly go to error: errorResponse after check the success: function(data){ line -in firefox value not bind if i use debugger;.

how to solve this error and why this code not work correctly in IE.

Comment: What is errorresponse then?

Comment: errorResponse show the alert

Comment: I mean `xhr.status` and `xhr.responseText`

Comment: xhr.status 0 and responseText error. I'm not sure bcos some time alert also not work properly

Comment: `xhr.status = 0` caused by cross domain request. You set crossDomin( this must be crossDomain as @Felix stated) but you need to allow `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on server side. I mean requested server. your requested url and client url is different right?

Comment: it's any way to change the Access-Control-Allow-Origin In client side

Comment: it's work in other browser but in IE it's not working . I'm using jquery 1.10.2 due to this any problem arive

Comment: Nope, you need to allow that on server side. Your urls are different right?

Comment: then how it's work on firefox and chrome.

Comment: I couldn't get that case also.

Comment: Ok I check any other solution present . If my data binding to dropdown code is correct or not..?

Comment: @huseyin-babal, you don't need to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` here. @Gurunathan is using JSONP, which is an old trick to by-pass same-origin-policy. Current modern way is Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS), CORS requires you supply `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` (and much more), JSONP doesn't use it.

Comment: @Gurunathan could you please put your backend code on your question also?

Comment: backend of web service or my Page Code

Comment: backend. You are using jspnp, I want to know how you used backend code to response